# python socket file read timeout?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using a python socket as a file to talk to another process:

```
def connect(self):
    try:
        self.sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect( (self.target, self.port) )
        self.fobj = self.sock.makefile()
```

Normally I'd write a command through the socket and expect a reply within a certain period. So my question is: is there a way to achieve timeout when reading a line from the socket file object?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to use [settimeout()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by saying **way to achieve timeout**, are you asking for capturing exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [Python's documentation about `socket.makefile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile):

> socket.makefile([mode[, bufsize]])
>
> Return a file object associated with the socket. (File objects are described in File Objects.) The file object references a dup()ped version of the socket file descriptor, so the file object and socket object may be closed or garbage-collected independently. **The socket must be in blocking mode (it can not have a timeout)**. The optional mode and bufsize arguments are interpreted the same way as by the built-in file() function.

Therefore you can't have a timeout on a socket-file, if you need timeouts, you must use regular sockets.

Comment: Although the documentation says so, it is actually possible and reliable to use timeouts. This was tested on linux and windows with python 2.7.14

Comment: @NameOfTheRose do you have any reference to backup your claim?

Comment: @eric, sorry for the delayed response. What do you mean by reference? I have a working program that does that. If you are still interested I will try to post a minimum program demonstrating it.

Comment: you claim it's reliable, is it documented anywhere? By reference I mean documentation.